# scanf format-specifiers i want to get input and assign to two string variables in one go

Tags: c, scanf, string-formatting

I'm learning the C programming, want to get grip on the scanf function.

```
#include<stdio.h>                                                                                                                         

int main() {                                                       

    char s1[20], s2[20];                                                   

    scanf("%[^0-9]s%[0-9]s",s1,s2); // [^0-9] stops assging when encounters                                       
                                    // [0-9] expects only 0-9 and assigs    
    puts(s1);                                                             
    puts(s2);                                                             
    return 0;                                                                                                               
}
```

By running the program:

```
asdasd123123
asdasd
ç£nU
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are confusing the two formats `%[]` and `%s` with `%[]s` which expects to find an `'s'` next.

Comment: scanf("[^\n]s",s) works fine and   %[^0-9]s also works

Comment: is there any online resourses that can help me read...

Comment: The man page for `scanf`. But it is long and tricky, perhaps several pages.

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf`.  If it's not returning 2, then `s2` is not being filled in with anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your `scanf()` syntax is off just a bit :

```
int main() {
    char s1[20], s2[20];

    scanf("%[^0-9]%[0-9]", s1, s2); // [^0-9] stops assging when encounters     
                                      // [0-9] expects only 0-9 and assigs    
    puts(s1);
    puts(s2);

    return 0;
}
```

And it is definitely a good idea to check the return value of `scanf()`, particularly when trying to read into multiple variables, to see how many were actually assigned values.

```
#define NUM_ARGS 2

int main() {
    char s1[20], s2[20];
    int ret;

    if ((ret = scanf("%[^0-9]%[0-9]", s1, s2)) != NUM_ARGS) {
        printf("ERROR\n");
    } else {
        puts(s1);
        puts(s2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you also describe the defferences between %[^\n]s and %[^\n] ?

Comment: `%[^\n]` includes an implicit `s`, since it is specifying the characters to read or, in this case, to not read.  So, the `s` is not needed for the `%`.  The `s` you include is an extra literal `s` in the format basically saying, there should be an `s` next in the input.

Comment: im not good at understanding english,  can you explain it in simple words, thank you!!!